# Maven - How to solve branch and trunk builds

Tags: maven

I have the following SVN structure (it is what it is .. I cannot change it )

```
where branches / trunk represent directory 
X -> A -> branches -> A-branch-name -> pom.xml
       -> trunk -> pom.xml      
  -> B -> branches -> B-branch-name-> pom.xml
       -> trunk-> pom.xml
--> pom.xml
```

X contains pom.xml to build all modules - A , B .. and branch-name is same for all modules.

How do i configure maven so that it can build branch or  trunk based 
on some parameter passed ? or suggest and alternative.

Comment: Firstly, X is a modular project? Also What do you mean with **build branch or trunk**? How to manage your builds ?

Comment: The build will be triggered from X where the pom.xml resides containing <modules><module>A/trunk</module> <module>b/trunk</module></modules>

Answer (score 0):

Then, if you use maven like tool of porject managment you can use [maven-release-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/) to manage branch, release and tag in a smart way. Also I'm working with maven modular project

```
|-- parent
    |-- model
        pom.xml
    |-- services
        pom.xml
    |-- rest
        pom.xml
    |-- web-app
        pom.xml
pom.xml
```

and on my SCM i have the following layout

```
|--trunk
   parent0.0.1Snap(and sub modules)
|--branch
   parent0.0.2Snap(and sub modules)
|--tags
```

Finally to manage the build of both parent0.0.1Snap and parent0.0.2Snap this depend of your way to build. If you are using Jenkins for example you can make two different job.